# ERROR TypeError: "_co.voiture is undefined" how to fix this error

Tags: angular

I have a problem with this code however it gives me a return but it turns out that one says my car object is not defined

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { VoitureService } from '../services/voiture.service';
import { Voiture } from '../Voiture.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-voiture',
  templateUrl: './single-voiture.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-voiture.component.css']
})

export class SingleVoitureComponent implements OnInit {

   voiture : Voiture[];
   voitureId : number;

   constructor(
     private serviceVoiture: VoitureService, 
     private route: ActivatedRoute
   ) { 
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     const voitureId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];      
     this.serviceVoiture
       .getVoiture(voitureId)
       .subscribe(data => { this.voiture = data });
   }

}
```

my Function get voiture return on Voiture with Id

```
 getVoiture (id):Observable<Voiture[]>{
   return this.http.get<Voiture[]>(this.url+'/'+id);
 }
```

However when I click on a link I am redirected in the right page and with the data requested but it comes to me an error:

> type ERROR TypeError: "_co.voiture is undefined"

Comment: I remember I'm beginner in angular but I do not see what's wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing your array to 'empty' at definition:

```js
export class SingleVoitureComponent implements OnInit {

   voiture : Voiture[] = [];

...
```

Your component may be rendering before your get subscription returns and sets `this.voiture` to a value.  Initializing `voiture` ensures that the array is defined, even if it is empty.

And welcome to SO!